# Drawing squares 1 miles x 1 mile

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API V3 to draw squares of 1 mile by 1 mile.

**Problem:** From the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#RectangleOptions), the `bounds` property can be used to define the size of the rectangle object, but in terms of LatLng coordinates. Given a particular point's LatLng, how can we draw a rectangle 1 mile by 1 mile, or 1 km by 1 km?

**Update:** What I am trying to do is to divide a state say Philadelphia into 10 mile by 10 mile squares. It does not need to be very precise.

Comment: but the point it's in the center of the square?

Comment: it can be anywhere... what I am trying to do is to divide a state say Philadelphia into 10 mile by 10 mile squares. It does not need to be very precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind that the Earth's surface is curved; it is impossible to truly divide it up into squares.  The squares that make up a Google map are longer on the bottom than they are on the top.  This will make your map somewhat more complicated.

Comment: In the southern hemisphere, the squares are longer on the top than they are at the bottom as well... for those in the negative latitudes :-)

Comment: D'oh!  Sorry about that, southerners.  In my defense, OP specifically mentioned dividing up Pennsylvania, which is well north of the equator.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate miles or kilometres to difference in latitude or longitude. This web page gives javascript code. 
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Or, simpler: One degree of latitude is pretty much 69 miles anywhere on the planet, so 10 miles will be ~0.1449 degree. 'Longitudal' degrees vary greatly depending on where you are in terms of latitude. You should calculate it:

one degree distance in miles = (PI/180) * 3,963 * cos(latitude)

As long as you keep the rectangles relatively small the fact that the Earth is a sphere shouldn't make a lot of difference. Civil engineers usually base their work on the flat earth theory, because it's good enough in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

the link below lets you Compute lat/lon given radial and distance from a known point
http://williams.best.vwh.net/gccalc.htm, i believe it is simplied version of the above link

Assuming the latitude and longitude you have is the center, you can find the corners of the rectangle giving the radius as 45,135,225,315 and distance as 5miles.

Hope, this helps.